# Use of Listen() sys call in a multi threaded TCP server

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I am in the middle of a multi-threaded TCP server design using Berkely SOCKET API under linux in system independent C language. The Server has to perform I/O multiplexing as the server is a centralized controller that manages the clients (that maintain a persistent connection with the server forever (unless a machine on which client is running fails etc)). The server needs to handle a minimum of 500 clients.
I have a 16 core machine, what I want is that I spawn 16 threads(one per core) and a main thread. The main thread will `listen()` to the connections and then dispatch each connection on the queue list to a thread which will then call `accept()` and then use the `select()` sys call to perform I/O multiplexing. Now the problem is how do I know that when to dispatch a thread to call `accept()` . I mean how do I find out in the main thread that there is a connection pending at the `listen()` so that I can assign a thread to handle that connection. All help much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if each of your 16 threads is going to be running `select` (or poll, or whatever) anyway, there is no problem with them all adding the server socket to their select sets.

More than one may wake when the server socket has in incoming connection, but only one will *successfully* call `accept`, so it should work.

Pro: easy to code.

Con:

- naive implementation doesn't balance load (would need eg. global
  stats on number of accepted sockets handled by each thread, with
  high-load threads removing the server socket from their select sets)
- thundering herd behaviour could be problematic at high accept rates

Comment: Thanks alot that makes my job a bit easier. I could try something to balance the load but would there be any elegant way to avoid the thundering herd behavior? what If there is a case that accept occurs only at the start that is for example there are 500 clients and all request connection at the startup ? once they all are connected and each thread then performs the I/O multiplexing on its select set ? will that be a decent enough scenario to use this approach ?

Comment: In that case just make sure the `listen` queue is good and long, and figure out the load balancing.  If there is always something to `accept` (until everyone is connected), very few of the wakeups will be wasted. It's only a thundering herd if a single event triggers multiple spurious wakeups - if there's real work that can be done in parallel, it's actually ideal.

Answer (score 2):

The listen() function call prepares a socket to accept incoming connections.  You then use select() on that socket and get a notification that a new connection has arrived.  You then call accept on the server socket and a new socket id will be returned.  If you like you can then pass that socket id onto your thread.

What I would do is have a single thread for accepting connections and receiving data which then dispatches the data to a queue as a work item for processing.

Answer (score 0):

epoll or aio/asio.  I suspect you got no replies to your earlier post because you didn't specify linux when you asked for a scalable high-performnce solution.  Asynchronous solutions on different OS are implemented with substantial kernel support and linux aio, Windows IOCP etc. are different enough that 'system independent' does not really apply - nobody could give you an answer.

Now that you have narrowed the OS down to linux, look up the appropriate asynchronous solutions.